# ServiceHost message receive event?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, servicehost

Surely there must be an event to attach onto before a ServiceHost or Channel or Dispatcher handles a message? I'm assuming it can be accessed through OperationContext.Current, but the closest events I can find are Opening and Closing. Is there something like a MessageReceived or BeforeMessageProcessed event?

If not using events, is there some other way using WCF classes/configuration to determine if a ServiceHost SingletonInstance is currently processing a DataContract?

EDIT: IDispatchMessageInspector (AfterReceiveRequest and BeforeSendReply) is perfect. I have about 8 services and need to know what messages (DataContracts) they are currently processing. While it would be possible to use something like a helper method that takes a delegate and does BeforeReceive(); InvokeDelegate(); AfterReceive(); it's far easier to use IDispatchMessageInspector and behaviors.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there isn't such an event at the service host level directly. Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Normally, if you've got any processing that must be done whenever a message arrives, then the right way is to use one of the several extensibility points that WCF offers for this, like [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx). In this case, you'd inject your message inspector into the WCF pipeline through a [service or an endpoint behavior](http://www.winterdom.com/wcf/winfx/web%20services/2006/10/18/iservicebehavioridispatchmessageinspectorandendpoints.html).